# How to solve "Domain's DNS record could not be retrieved" on Github page?

Tags: github, dns

This is my first time creating a custom domain on Github.

I have a domain with domain.com and I have followed every step necessary such as adding Alias and CNAME as well as the IP addresses. However, I keep getting this error

> Both beatricewambuimbugua.com and its alternate name are improperly configured
> Domain's DNS record could not be retrieved. For more information, see Learn more (InvalidDNSError). We recommend you add an A record pointed to our IP addresses, or an ALIAS record pointing to beatricewambuimbugua.github.io.

What am I doing wrong?
[Alias and CNAME entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1rUW.png)

Also when I run `$ dig beatricewambuimbugua.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd` 
I get this result: `;; global options: +cmd ;beatricewambuimbugua.com.  IN  A`

showcasing the IP addresses are not noticed.

Comment: See https://dnsviz.net/d/beatricewambuimbugua.com/Yd2Zgg/dnssec/ you are in a lame delegation scenario your DNS setup is invalid. You need to fix that first.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek how do I fix that?